# Node.js - unable to save entire output of `git clone` command using child_process spawnSync

Tags: node.js, git, child-process

**What I want to do:**

I am using Node.js to execute `git clone` command using [child_process.spawnSync()](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options) and then save the output in a variable for later usage.

**Example:**

For example, I want to execute `git clone https://github.com/octo-org/public-repo.git` and save the resulting output in a variable:

```
Cloning into 'public-repo'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 3, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
```

**Failed Attempt 1: only able to save first line of output (not the entire output)**

However, I am only able to save the first line of output (i.e., `Cloning into 'public-repo'...`) in a variable. Here is what I have so far:

```
const args = ["clone", "https://github.com/octo-org/public-repo.git"];
const child = require("child_process").spawnSync("git", args);
const output = `${child.stderr}`;
console.log(output); // only returns "Cloning into 'public-repo'..."
```

**Failed Attempt 2: entire output is printed to console, but i need to save it in a variable**

Also, I looked into `inherit` option of [options.stdio](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio). Although it prints the entire result (instead of just the first line), I need to save the result in a variable. So, `options = { stdio: "inherit" }` will print the full output, but I need to save the full output in a variable. Here is my code for that:

```
// this solution prints the full output
// but i need to save the full output in a variable

const args = ["clone", "https://github.com/octo-org/public-repo.git"];
const options = { stdio: "inherit" };
const child = require("child_process").spawnSync("git", args, options);
```

**Failed Attempt 3: redirect output to file (`>`) only writes the first line**

Someone suggested redirecting output to file (`>`), but this also results in only the first line of output (`Cloning into 'public-repo'...`) being written to `readme.txt` file

```
require("child_process").exec(
  "git clone https://github.com/octo-org/public-repo.git 2> readme.txt",
  { stdio: "inherit", shell: true },
  (error, stdout, stderror) => {}
);
```

**Question:**

How can I use Node.js [Child Processes](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) to save the entire `git clone` output in a variable? So far, I am only able to print/display the entire output (but not save it in a variable). Also, I am only able to save the first line of output (but not the entire output) after executing `git clone` command.

Comment: Do you think If you output all the result in a single file and then read the file with `fs` and input it into a variable is a better solution?

Comment: It depends on OS for example for Linux: `git clone https://github.com/octo-org/public-repo.git > readme.txt`

Comment: @El. I tried your suggestion `git clone https://github.com/octo-org/public-repo.git > readme.txt` using Node.js Child Processes and it only returns the first line (`Cloning into 'public-repo'...`). Your suggestion works fine if I manually type the command in the terminal, but not using Node.js child_process

Comment: edit: I meant to say I tried `git clone https://github.com/octo-org/public-repo.git 2> readme.txt`. Notice I am using `2>` to redirect to stderr because `git clone` outputs to stderr even if status == 0 (i.e. success).

Comment: nice work @kimbaudi

Answer (score 4):

Okay, so I figured out how to capture the entire output from executing `git clone` command by passing the `--progress` option to `git clone` (i.e., `git clone --progress <some_remote_url>`).

According to [git clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---progress) documentation, we can pass `--progress` option to force progress status even if the stderr stream isn't directed to a terminal.

Since the progress status was directed at a terminal and I was spawning a child process that is not attached to a terminal, I could not capture the progress output.

So here is the updated Node.js code passing `--progress` option to capture the entire output of `git config`:

```
// adding --progress works

const args = [
  "clone",
  "https://github.com/octo-org/public-repo.git",
  "--progress"
];
const child = require("child_process").spawnSync("git", args);
console.log(`${child.stderr}`);
```